# Trying to link my github repo to cpanel throws an error

Tags: github, deployment, cpanel, cloning

I'm currently trying to link my private repo in github to cpanel.

**Steps I took:**

1. Generated new SSH keys in cpanel SSH Access > authorized public key
2. Went to my github private repo > settings > Deploy Keys > added the public key with write access
3. Went to cpanel Git Version Control and added my ssh clone link git@github.com:gitHubUser/githubrepo.git

I end up with this and I'm struggling to debug it
[image: cpanel error]

It looks to me that I have no access to my own repo even after adding the SSH key